# Does Batman get sick from common diseases?

Tags: dc, batman

As a human he should get sick normally, but has that been shown in the comics? (like cold, flu, stomach ache, or headache)

Comment: Not from the comic, but there's an entire episode of TAS where he catches a cold while fighting Mr. Freeze, and then defeats him with a thermos of hot chicken noodle soup.

Comment: that sounds more like the 60s series...

Comment: I know.  It was amazing.

Comment: @JeanPaul - only if it was the *Bat* Chicken Soup.

Comment: Even if he did, would he care?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In the Knightfall storyline it is shown that Batman is suffering from an illness (most likely a cold) and severe fatigue. He seeks the assistance of doctors but is told he just needs to rest. Unfortunately he isn't able to get it and is brought to his mental and physical limits as Bane releases all the inmates from Arkham Asylum.

Batman is so determined to keep going he often does not let injuries and sickness prevent him from his crime fighting. There are times in the comics where he gets sick or injured and is told to rest and stop, but you see him immediately get dressed and leave when something new develops.

[image]

Comment: and if you're wondering how he can keep going and ever get better, and how come it's so rare in the first place, it's because he has a very strong constitution, as you would expect. example from Batman #72: http://nachtkriecher.com/downloads/batman-constitution.png

Comment: @Nacht, you mean his very strong... Batstitution.